# how to get input new attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try set new value for input 'pid' attribute and get this, but I get `null`.

I have this code in jquery:

```
$(".feauter-product-holder").click(function () {
  $("#productsubject").attr("pid", $(this).find("input[type=hidden]").attr("id"));
});
```

and my code in HTML:

```
<div class='feauter-product-holder'>
  <input type="hidden" id="3">
</div>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="productsubject" pid=""></asp:TextBox></div>
 $.ajax({
                    url: editor.config.saveSubmitURL,//the url to post at... configured in config.js
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { servicename: "savedata", text: data, subject: $("#productsubject").val(), pid: $("input[id$='productsubject").attr("pid") },//editor.name contains the id of the current editable html tag
                })
```

i edit this post
i write wrong class div,but in my code is correct.
when i call pid in ajax i get null

What should I do?

Comment: `class='feauter-product-holder'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove "." from class name in DIV and then 
you can try like this :-

```
$(".feauter-product-holder").click(function () {
  $("input[id$='productsubject']").attr("pid", $(this).find("input[type=hidden]").attr("id"));
});
```

While Handling with ASP control with Jquery you use like (Element ends with selector)
example :- `$("input[id$='productsubject']")` .. `$("#productsubject")` won't work .

Actually in ASP.NET if you use asp control with some ID, ASP.NET [Naming container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) changes the control ID like `ctl001_yourcontrolID` to avoid conflicts. Hence, in Jquery when you select a element by simply its ID(like `$("#productsubject")`) , you will not get that element since its ID has been changed. to illustrate, you can inspect the asp control in Firebug or chrome's inspect element.

Hence when you write `$("input[id$='productsubject']")` ,it select the element whose ID ends with `productsubject`.

Comment: you are missing single quotes in ajax call :- here `$("input[id$='productsubject")`

Comment: very thank's.
can you explain me about your answer? about id$ and single quotes

Answer (score 5):

Your DIV can't be found because of a wrong css class call. Try:

```
<div class="feauter-product-holder">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems - the class on the div is incorrect, and also .net will change the id of the text box.

Try

```
<div class="feauter-product-holder">
```

for the div.

If you are using .net 4 you can set ClientIDMode="Static" on the text box like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="productsubject" pid="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox></div>
```